# Sum the ID based on other column entries

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
------------------------------
|SampleID |DrugName |Result  |
------------------------------
|Sample1  |Drug1    |Positive|
|Sample1  |Drug2    |Positive|
|Sample2  |Drug1    |Positive|
|Sample2  |Drug2    |Negative|
|Sample2  |Drug3    |Positive|
```

......

I want to get

```
-----------------------
|1stDrug|2ndDrug|Count|
-----------------------
|Drug1  |Drug2  |1    |
|Drug1  |Drug3  |1    |
|Drug2  |Drug3  |0    |
```

......

I basically want to count samples which had drug combinations positive using SQL. This will let me know "Drug1 and Drug2 were together positive in X number of samples", "Drug 1 and Drug 3 were positive in Y number of samples", etc. There is no finite sample ID and a large number of drugs so I can't hardcode any of the sample IDs or Drug names to the query. None of the columns will have nulls though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you relating Result1 to Result2 in your expected results?

Comment: Result1 and Result2 are seen positive within the same sample. I.e. Drug1 and Drug2 are seen together positive in 1 sample. I changed the column names as the headings seem to be a bit confusing

Comment: Your logic is still not very clear. What happens when you have 3 drugs that are all positive? Why is the combination of Drug1 and Drug2 listed with a `Count` of 1 when they both occur in Sample1 and Sample2 with different Results? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, @digital.aaron. The if all drugs are positive I an hoping to get a 1 added to Drug1 and Drug2 and Drug1 and Drug3 and Drug2 and Drug3. Drug1 and Drug2 is having count 1 above because Drug1 and Drug2 together positive only in 1 sample and that is Sample1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t1.drug as drug1, t2.drug as drug2,
       sum(case when t1.result = 'positive' and
                     t2.result = 'positive'
                then 1
                else 0
           end) / 2
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.sample = t2.sample and t1.drug < t2.drug
group by t1.drug, t2.drug;
```

Comment: Thanks. Counting based on positives and summing them gave me some new ideas. I am trying them out. I could not use this exactly because t1 and t2 is the same table. I am not sure how to join within the same table.

Comment: @manjulapra . . . You use table aliases as the example in this answer shows.

Comment: Thanks. In "case when result=...." part is it t1.result or t2.resut? When having just "result" it throws an error saying ambiguous column name.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it is "t1.drug<>t2.drug", isn't it? Also, I am having trouble understanding the following part of the algorithm:
'else -1
           end) / 2'
What does this part do? Also, this gives a lot of negative counts!

Comment: @manjulapra . . . Each pair only need to appear once which is why `<` is used instead of `<>`.  I think the `-1` was because I originally misunderstood the calculation.  I think I understand it better now.